# Missing `/dev/sda` when building a minimal kernel for VMware

Tags: linux-kernel, drivers, buildroot

I'm trying to build a minimal Linux kernel using buildroot that I want to run on VMware, among other platforms. However, when I boot the kernel it doesn't recognize the hard drive (i.e., no `/dev/sda`). I think I have enabled all the drivers needed, but still nothing. It does work on Virtualbox, but not on VMware.

```
lspci | less
...
00:07.1 IDE interface: Intel Corporation 82371AB/EB/MB PIIX4 IDE (rev01)
...
00:10.0 SCSI storage controller: LSI Logic / Symbios Logic 53c1030 PCI-X Fusion-MPT Dual Ultra320 SCSI (rev 01)
...
```

I've started with `make x86_64_defconfig` And I've enabled:

```
SCSI device support:
    <M> SCSI disk support
    <M> SCSI generic support

Serial ATA and Parallel ATA drivers (libata)
    <M>   AHCI SATA support
    <M>   Platform AHCI SATA support
    <M>       Intel ESB, ICH, PIIX3, PIIX4 PATA/SATA support
    <M>     Generic ATA support
```

Is there something I am missing? Can I find a configuration file for a typical desktop kernel and base my configuration upon it? Are there any more tricks I can use to figure out which modules I need to build? Can I use some identifier to search in the source code of the kernel for example?

Comment: 1) surely you'd prefer AHCI? 2) yes, /boot/config* 3) to disable unused modules you can run make localmodconfig in the VM http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/275747/29483

Comment: Added the AHCI module as well, or did you mean something else? I'll take a look at the `/boot/config` file

Comment: Yep.  AHCI is a better interface, and it's used across physical systems from multiple vendors.  If there's a default hardware model for modern OS's, it probably uses AHCI.  Except that you might also want to be able to take advantage of virt-specific drivers.  E.g.  https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/VMware/Installing_Arch_as_a_guest#In-kernel_drivers  Typically module names are mentioned in Kconfig and you can search for them (I think "/" key or ctrl+f in make xconfig).  Or I think `git grep vmw_pvscsi` should find the Kconfig file and identify the corresponding CONFIG_ option.

Comment: I copied the config file used on my desktop, so now I got the module. I know this since `find /lib/modules/$(uname -r) -name '*.ko' -exec basename '{}' .ko ';' | xargs modprobe` make `/dev/sda` appear. Now only to find out which module makes `/dev/sda` to appear :-D

Comment: Have you created an initrd file with the necessary modules?

Comment: No, since I don't know which module(s) I need....

Comment: You don't want to run `make localmodconfig` inside the VM?  To find the ata driver, look at `readlink -f /sys/class/ata*/*`.  That will show the pci device, then you can find name of the module for it e.g. `cat readlink /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1f.2/driver/module`

Comment: I don't have gnu make and not the kernel source code inside the VM

Comment: "Can I find a configuration file for a typical desktop kernel and base my configuration upon it?" Yes, of course. Look inside `/boot`. That's where the config file for your installed kernels live. And start with a config corresponding to a working kernel, and selectively disable stuff, not the other way around.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved my problem the ugly way. I'll wait with marking this as correct as I think there is a better solution.

After trying a variety of solutions, among other trying to get information 
from `/sys/` (`readlink /sys/block/sda/device/driver` etc). But I only found information that it was some kind of SCSI driver, which didn't help me. Finally I used my desktop kernel configuration, and loaded all the modules until `/dev/sd*` appeared. I was at first tricked by loading `scsi_debug`, which also presents a `/dev/sda`. The module i needed was `mptspi`, which is enabled by `FUSION_SPI` in the Linux kernel. I learned this after searching the source code tree. This is the script I used for identifying the driver:

```
for MODULE in $(find /lib/modules/$(uname -r) -name '*.ko' -exec basename '{}' .ko ';')
do
    echo "Loading $MODULE"
    modprobe -D $MODULE
    modprobe $MODULE
    ls /dev/sd* 2>&1
done
```

Which I ran as

```
./script | tee script.log
```

Next time I'll probably set up some solution using `mdev`/`udev`...

Answer (score 0):

Maybe your disk is on `LVM` partition . check :
/dev/mapper/lvm
and also you can use `df` or `lsblk` command to find that path of your disk.
`mount` command will also helps.

Comment: Sorry, but this is before that. I don't even see `/dev/sda` to be able to set up a partition table